# parse.com Javascript: parseObject parse method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

what is the equivalent for backbone model Parse method in parseObject?

i couldn't find it and my parse method is not being called.

i need to parse the data i get from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the backbone-parse library: https://github.com/neebz/backbone-parse